# Android Eclipse Log.d() is suddenly only working very intermittently

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, logcat, android-logcat

Suddenly today, only some (and not very many) Log.d() calls show up in the logcat window.  In one instance, the code is like this:

```
    Log.d(TAG, ">DataPartial:  " + KillData.bDataPartial);
    Log.d(TAG, ">DataEmpty:    " + KillData.bDataEmpty);
    Log.d(TAG, ">DataPending:  " + KillData.bDataPending);
    Log.d(TAG, ">DataComplete: " + KillData.bDataComplete);
```

Only the last line was generating a line in logcat.  When I commented that line out, nothing showed up.

There are occasionally other ungrouped calls to Log.d(), but they don't seem to be showing up either.

Scratching my head!

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when I rebooted my PC. I had tried shutting down & restarting eclipse without luck.  Also, tried logging out of Windows and logging back in, but no luck there either.

Weird.